# XML AND RSS Feed issues

Tags: xml, rss

IE states it cant display this feed

While GC displays - refer to image attached[image]

What am i lacking in displaying the feed?(I am using localhost)

I was told i cant use localhost, any ideas on how to make my rss feed function?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have prefixed your RSS feed with an HTML document. Don't do that.

Do [validate](http://feedvalidator.org/) your markup.

Comment: How do i use the validate my markup with the site provided?
I am using localhost.(Am relatively new to this area)

Comment: [Run it locally](http://feedvalidator.org/about.html) (or find another feed validator that accepts file uploads).

Comment: Pardon me but in what format do i upload the file, as the file i have used to generate this is a php script which retreieves information from my database.

Comment: The format you get when you save the output of the PHP program.

Comment: I am sincerely sorry but i do not get the purpose of validating my markup, what is the reason my code fails to get displayed properly?
could you please explain in layman terms. Cheers Mate

Comment: Validating markup will tell you where you have errors in it. It would pick up such huge errors as "Putting an HTML document in front of it"